# Refatoração de código em C

Tags: c, refatoração

Estive hoje tentando criar um simples programinha e C com alguns colegas e um dos questionamentos foi: No `else if` seria realmente necessário colocarmos as validações `precoAtual >= 30` e `vendaMedia >= 500`...já que o `if` está verificando? Bem, olhando rapidamente **sim** para verificarmos a **igualdade** em ambas condições e outra é que como o `if`possui um ou (`||`) assim a condição não seria 100% valida ou algo do tipo ...mas queríamos ir mais fundo e ter um justificativa com maior propriedade..e nada saiu. Alguém saberia justificar? Posso realmente refatorar o código retirando essas validações?

PS.: Fiz teste de mesa mas não consegui concluir nada.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

 int main(){
  float vendaMedia, precoAtual;
  printf("Digite o preco atual:");
  scanf("%f", &precoAtual);
  printf("Digite o valor da venda media:");
  scanf("%f", &vendaMedia);
  if(precoAtual < 30 || vendaMedia < 500){
     precoAtual = precoAtual * 1.10;
     }
  else if((precoAtual >= 30 && precoAtual < 80) || (vendaMedia >= 500 && vendaMedia < 1200)){
     precoAtual = precoAtual * 1.15;
     }
  else{
     precoAtual = precoAtual * 1.20;
     }
  printf("%.2f \n", precoAtual);
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pense assim, se você entrar naquele `else if` isso significa que o primeiro `if` falhou. Isso equivale a expressão `precoAtual < 30 || valorMedia < 500` ter valor `false`. Quando que uma operação `||` retorna verdadeiro? Quando pelo menos um dos operandos é verdadeiro.

Se isso retornou falso, os dois são falsos. Se os dois operandos são falsos você nega eles e ve o que você obtém. É fácil ver que a negação dos dois é justamente `precoAtual >= 30` e `valorMedia >= 500`. Por isso essas verificações não são necessárias.

Perceba que essas duas expressões aparecem respectivamente em

```
precoAtual >= 30 && precoAtual < 80

valorMedia >= 500 && valorMedia < 1200
```

Ambos são verdadeiros desde que os dois operandos sejam verdadeiros. Você já sabe que os dois operandos da esquerda são verdadeiros, então o que realmente decide é o que sobrou na direita.

Em geral, quando você quer saber se uma verificação é mesmo necessária num `else if` você pensa nessa linha "se você chegou ali então a verificação anterior falhou" e então você ve quais condições são necessárias praquela verificação falhar.

Answer (score 0):

As primeiras condicoes no `else if`, tanto para o `precoAtual` quanto para `vendaMedia`, sao o complementar das condicoes no `if`. Logo, voce pode tirar a primeira verificacao, ja que se `precoAutal` nao e `< 30` ele tem que ser `>= 30` e o mesmo para `vendaMedia`.

Talvez fique confuso pois as condicoes no `else if` tem interseccao com a do `if`, mas como so um e executado na cadeia nao ha problema.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

 int main(){
  float vendaMedia, precoAtual;
  printf("Digite o preco atual:");
  scanf("%f", &precoAtual);
  printf("Digite o valor da venda media:");
  scanf("%f", &vendaMedia);
  if(precoAtual < 30 || vendaMedia < 500){
     precoAtual = precoAtual * 1.10;
     }
  else if(precoAtual < 80 || vendaMedia < 1200){
     precoAtual = precoAtual * 1.15;
     }
  else{
     precoAtual = precoAtual * 1.20;
     }
  printf("%.2f \n", precoAtual);
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```